# android passing json data into listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm really not to familiar when it comes to `ListView` and list adapters so I am going to need a little help here.  I need somebody to tell me what is wrong with my code and also what I can do to fix this problem. When I wrote this code I was new to the `ListView` so I apologize if my code seems crazy.

Main `Activity` code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button getanswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new asynctask().execute();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        });
    } 
}

      class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

             private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "ResultsSet";
             private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "Subject";
             private static final String TAG_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS = "Answers";
            public JSONArray json;

         @Override
         protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

             JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

             String URI = "http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswerService/V1/questionSearch?appid=dF39jyvV34FlZGhhMRBNHhILlsMJWLgBhxp4YrXImT2EOFprfUK3f4w2eGKjC5TC0A&query=sort&type=resolved&results&output=json";

             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

             return json ;

         }{ }
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                 JSONArray ResultsSet = null; {
                 try {
                     ResultsSet = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
             }

            return;
        }}}
```

`ListView` code :

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ResultsSet = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String TAG_SUBJECT = "Subject";
        String TAG_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";

        ResultsSet.add(map);


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, ResultsSet,
                R.layout.listview,
                 new String[] { TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ListView.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Subject"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NumAnswers"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

    </TextView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</TextView>
```

here is my stacktrace it's pretty long

```
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:747)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-25 12:27:45.055: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sorry for not asking a question the proper way and sorry for the log stacktrace but I just want to know why am I getting these errors and how can I prevent it.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are having and possibly ask a question? ;) Also post logcat if it is crashing

Comment: you may follow http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ this will really helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer, don't know yet without a question but its too hard to explain in a comment. But I see a few things that may give you issues.

This code may cause you trouble

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new asynctask().execute();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

If you are expecting your `AsyncTask` to fill your `ArrayList` you have to know that there is no guarantee that it will finish before your next `Activity` loads. You should probably start your `ListView` Activity in the `onPostExecute()`.

In your `ListViewActivity` you are adding `map` to `ResultSet` but I don't see where `map` is populated at all.

However, you don't even need a separate `Activity`. You can just call `setListAdapter(adapter)` in your `onPostExecute()` of your `MainActivity` and extend `ListActivity` there. I hope some of this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial it explains how to show data from JSON to a Listview

http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse

The most basic thing you might be missing is adding data to the `ListAdapter` so make sure that `ResultsSet` contains some data.

Refer Parsing JSON data and updating into ListView  part in this too

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Your exception has nothing to do with JSON parsing, it has to do with the Layout for your ListView.  My guess is that somewhere in your Layout file you have something like this

```
<TextView
  <!-- params -->
  >
  <!-- More Stuff -->
</TextView>
```

That is not possible because TextView cannot have any other views inside of it.  Make the layout in `R.Layout.listview` a `ViewGroup` such as a `LinearLayout` and then apply codeMagic's suggestions about requesting and parsing.

Edit: I'm editing this a second time because I didn't read that layout close enough the first time.  The underlying problem is that you have a `TextView` which is your top level element and contains other elements within it.  Then, at inflation time, the LayoutInflater is trying to inflate your layout (don't worry about how this happens), and it is seeing "oh hey, this top level layout has other children within it, let me cast it to a `ViewGroup` so I can add children.  However, a `TextView` is not a view group and has no children, so that `ClassCastException` gets thrown.

More importantly, it seems like you don't fully understand how Adapters on lists work.  You need to have a separate layout which contains information on how any one item in the  `ListView` looks; then your mapping needs to reference TextViews within THAT layout.  When you attach the adapter, every item within the `ListView` inflates the smaller layout that you pointed to in your `setAdapter` call and sets the `TextView`s in that smaller layout.  These smaller layouts are then placed one on top of the other to make your list.